# How to fetch data from API for Botpress no code chatbot

Tags: axios, get, chatbot, rapidapi, botpress

I am trying to fetch the following data (movie title, movie poster, year of release, and movie review) with an API from RapidAPI to Botpress chatbot. I used the code below but its not fetching the data. Is there a better way to write the code?

I tried the code below and I got an error message?

```
 `const url = "https://moviesdatabase.p.rapidapi.com"
    const params = {
      title: workflow.title,
      year: workflow.year,
      genre: workflow.genre,
      poster: workflow.poster,
      plot: workflow.plot,
      apiKey: env.moviesDatabase,
      number: '3',
      sort: 'popularity',
      sortDirection: 'asc',
      addmovieInformation: 'true'
    }

    const response = await axios.get(url, { params })

    if (response.status === 200) {
      workflow.movieInfo = response.data.results
    }`
```

Comment: Including the error message in your question would go a long way to helping you solve this

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few tips to help fetch data from an API in Botpress:

Make sure the API URL and parameters are correct. Double check the API documentation for the exact endpoint URL, required params, etc.
Handle errors properly. Check response.status before trying to access the data, and handle any errors or non-200 status codes.
Use async/await for asynchronous code. API calls are async, so use await when calling axios.get() and make the function async.
Check the Axios response format. The data may be in response.data or a different property depending on the API.
Use try/catch to catch errors. Wrap the Axios call in a try/catch block to catch any errors.
Check for CORS issues. APIs need to enable CORS to allow requests from other sites. This can cause errors.
Make sure API key is valid. Double check the API key used in params is correct.
Print for debugging. Add console.log() for key variables to help debug.
Here is an updated example:

```
const getMovieData = async () => {
  try {
    const url = "https://moviesdatabase.p.rapidapi.com";
    const params = {
      // params
    };
    
    const response = await axios.get(url, {
      params,
      headers: {
        "X-RapidAPI-Key": env.RAPID_API_KEY  
      }
    });
    
    if(response.status === 200) {
      return response.data; 
    } else {
      throw new Error('Error fetching data');
    }
    
  } catch (error) {
    // handle error  
  }
}

const movieData = await getMovieData();
```